# How to pass RequestVerification token in $.fileDownload call using jquery.filedownload.js

Tags: jquery, download

I'm using the following code to download a file

```
            $.fileDownload("Account/downloadFile",
            {
                data: { AccountNumber: _accountNumber},
            successCallback: function () {

            },
            failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {

            },
            prepareCallback: function () {
                //logger.log(" File Downloaded ", "", "", "success");
            }
        });
```

I want to pass __RequestVerificationToken = $(':input:hidden[name*="RequestVerificationToken"]').val() in this call.

I'm not able to pass in the headers.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to the data parameter and change the `httpMethod` to POST as the antiforgery token is expected to be part of the form values.  You might also need to change the allowed method on the controller action.

```
$.fileDownload("Account/downloadFile", {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    data: {
       "AccountNumber": _accountNumber,
       "__RequestVerificationToken":  $(':input:hidden[name*="RequestVerificationToken"]').val() 
    },
    successCallback: function () {

    },
    failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {

    },
    prepareCallback: function () {
        //logger.log(" File Downloaded ", "", "", "success");
    }
});
```

Comment: Its not working. The token is passed with the data but it is not validating the ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute decorated in the downloadFile action. Throwing error.

Comment: @user3263194 have you verified that the antiforgery cookie is also being sent with the request. If both the cookie and token are being sent (with the proper names) it should pass the attribute's check.

Comment: Yes. The cookie is being sent with proper value.
The Query string params in the Network :
AccountNumber:20141121185358940
__RequestVerificationToken:l8r7-XZb7Zu9gRILxGc5d3f25BohC14oRHjY166IdNlQk69nsVe-GgtrIrGpmC5Y30g3xNZBIe4bcRnwVhkc-WDhHEA1

Cookie:__RequestVerificationToken=GqVpDfPb13N6b2MhP1uJHM4XtmQfC1qlwGsYHqO_dz6g4iHtHZQIpkLa4SPATmLEpigcXu-E2JZqP_JFMzYaVj4cDwE1;

Comment: @user3263194 Change the `httpMethod` to POST

Comment: After changing to POST, its not passing the query string parameters(not able to see in the network call). Still the same error I'm getting.

Comment: You should be able to see the form parameters in the browser developer tools network tab when you view the request details.

Comment: It is being passed with the data, but it is not available in HttpContext. HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] returns null.